# SQL get 10 most common Numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table where there is a Column called Error_Number, in there there are numbers from 1-infinity (in reality 109 atm) and I want to get the 10 most common numbers.
So the input looks like the following

| Date | Error_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 01.02.2021 | 1 |
| 01.02.2021 | 3 |
| 01.02.2021 | 2 |
| 01.02.2021 | 3 |
| 01.02.2021 | 2 |
| 01.02.2021 | 3 |
| 01.02.2021 | 5 |
| 01.02.2021 | 3 |
| 01.02.2021 | 2 |
| 01.02.2022 | 3 |
| 01.02.2022 | 2 |
| 01.02.2022 | 2 |
| 01.02.2022 | 7 |
| 01.02.2022 | 7 |
| 01.02.2022 | 3 |

And I would like to filter by Year and get a return like this for 2021

| Amount | Error_Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |

I have written this code so far:

```
Database.getExecuteQuery($"SELECT Error_Number FROM Table GROUP BY Error_Number ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");
```

However I want to get the most commmon Number and then the second most and so on. How do I implement this? And how do I get the Amount of the most common Number?

For my Implementation it would be most handy to get a separate output for the most, the second most etc. and also for the amount of that. Kinda complicated I know, I'm Sorry.

I'm using C# btw

Any help is greatly appreciated :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, what would top 10 do here? Also do you think mySQL recognizes top 10 ?

Comment: I doubt it does tbh

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (
select error_number, count(*) as Total
from myTable
group by error_number
) x
order by total desc
limit 10;
```

EDIT: It is C#, right?

```
Database.getExecuteQuery(@"select *
    from (
    select error_number, count(*) as Total
    from myTable
    group by error_number
    ) x
    order by total desc
    limit 10;");
```

EDIT: I didn't notice year filtering before:

```
select *
from (
select error_number, count(*) as Total
from myTable
where year(`Date`) = 2021
group by error_number
) x
order by total desc
limit 2;
```

And this is [DBFiddle sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3efa801c036279c18bc225987239306)

You would put that inside the double quotes.

Comment: What output do I get out of this? is it going to be a list or String or smth?
Sorry I'm a real noob when it comes to SQL, and maybe even programming in general

Comment: @thisisforwork, oh sorry I thought you knew that part, just replace with your query. I will edit anyway. It would return rows. I don't know the language you are using BTW, to give a better code.

Comment: Not only the subquery is useless but your query is wrong because sorting in a subquery does not guarantee that the outer select will select the rows in the same order.

Comment: @forpas, before spending such baseless sentences prototype and test it.

Comment: 'I would like to filter by Year and get a return like this for 2021' - you missed this bit..

Comment: Take some time to read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/184167/170431 and maybe you will learn something new.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes you are right I missed that. Will edit soon. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: @CetinBasoz thanks, I'm guessing I can then split the list however I want afterwards?

Comment: @thisisforwork, sorry I don't understand what split is here.

Comment: @forpas, ordering in subquery was a mistake, ok but why would that subquery be useless, would you care to explain that as well?

Comment: It is useless because you can apply order by and limit directly after the group by clause.

Comment: @forpas, it doesn't make it useless, you can do without it. Unnecessary and useless are not the same thing unless your target was insulting.

Comment: By useless I mean that you don't need an outer select. Only the select..group by..order by.. limit 10 is enough.

Comment: @forpas, ok but your wording is insulting. That is the only point. Unnecessary or you don't need would be appropriate but not "useless" which has totally a different meaning here.

Comment: *...the subquery is useless...* insulting? To whom? The subquery?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247481/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-forpas).